# Time attendance software to work in conjunction with ZKTeco ZK4500 Fingerprint Scanner

Tags: time-management

I'm searching for a time and attendance software that can work in conjunction with the ZKTeco ZK4500 Fingerprint Scanner (device specifications can be found [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjJxYD-uKDmAhXARxUIHR5hB5QQFjAAegQIARAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zkteco.com%2Fen%2Findex%2FService%2Fload%2Fid%2F502.html&usg=AOvVaw3XbCVpbP3dG7LLXrJl7lfC)).

Requirements

- Ideally, must be free to download and use
- MUST work with the ZK4500 Fingerprint Scanner
- Write to a SQL Based Database, like SQL Server Express
- Must be able to allow new people to be added to a database through the fingerprint scanner

I have searched for this type of software across the web, and have only come up with ZKTeco Attendance Management Software, but this doesn't seem to do what I want it to.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Such as, what about the product you mentioned did not satisfy your needs exactly?

Comment: Apologies. Should have added it in the original post. The ZKTeco Attendance Management Software only recognizes the ZK4500 as a fingerprint registration device, and not a time attendance logging device. I want the ZK4500 to be the time attendance logging device as well as the registration device. The software only allows exporting of existing employees to a recognized time attendance logging device, and nothing else.